# Python writes to file on same line continously

Tags: python

I have a code,which will increment the numbers of same line.When i open file and print it produces output with correct indentations as of original file.But when i write to a file,its writing output on same line

Coding:

```
import re

numbers = {}
with open('1.txt') as f,open('10.txt') as f1:
    for line in f:
        row = re.split(r'(\d+)', line.strip())
        words = tuple(row[::2])
        if words not in numbers:
            numbers[words] = [int(n) for n in row[1::2]]
        numbers[words] = [n+1 for n in numbers[words]]
        row[1::2] = map(str, numbers[words])
        print(''.join(row))
        f1.write(''.join(row))
```

1.txt

```
hello2 ram2
  hello2 ram2
   hello gate1
hello gate1
```

Writes as:

```
hello3 ram3 hello4 ram4 hello gate2 hello gate3
```

Instead of:

```
hello3 ram3
  hello4 ram4
   hello gate2
hello gate3
```

Its writing continously on the same line.please help me on how to write the file, as it produces on the stdout

Comment: You need to open f1 in write mode: `open('10.txt', 'wb') as f1`. If `f1` is opened in read mode, `f1.write` should have raised an IOError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
f1.write(''.join(row))
```

Can be modified to this to print a newline character to the output file:

```
f1.write(''.join(row) + '\n')
```

Writing `\n` will output the line separator character to the output file. As another poster pointed out there is a problem with the opening of the output file. You need to open it in write mode `'w'` so your with statement should read:

```
with open('1.txt') as f,open('10.txt', 'w') as f1:
```

One other thing is that you don't retain the indentation when outputting. that could be overcome with something like:

```
# Retrieve white space from original line
indentation = (re.match(r"\s*", line).group())
print (indentation + ''.join(row))
f1.write(indentation + ''.join(row) + '\n')
```

As a commenter posted, in Python3 you can print to a file directly instead of using write. So this is perfectly acceptable (and more consistent) too:

```
print(indentation + ''.join(row), file=f1)
```

Comment: No need for two function calls here... `f1.write(''.join(row) + '\n')`  is fine... If the OP is using Python 3.x you have the added bonus of being able to do `print(*row, sep='', file=f1)`

Comment: @Jon Why not... f1.write('\n'.join(row))?

Comment: @chishaku because all elements of `row` will end up on separate lines? (Which doesn't make it a row anymore)

Comment: Your edit is a bit weird... don't add the `\n` for the print as it's automatically added if not otherwise over-ridden, you also don't need the join or the string concat... just use `print(indentation, *row, file=f1)` (you might want a `sep=''` in there, but not sure)

Comment: I fixed it before you commented. Caught it right after I hit submit

Comment: I have a great liking for the Python 3 "print to a file" idiom, and use it whenever I'm in python 2.6 or later with `from __future__ import print_function`. Because of the uniformity offered, I would recommend including mention of it as well.